# PHP: error in fwrite() using SSL connection

Tags: php, ssl, fwrite, fsockopen

Im trying to send a email using SSL connection, but it returns error.
SSL connection is stablished successfully.
Im using fsockopen to open connection and fwrite to write on it.
Follow my code:

```
class smtp{

        var $conn;
        var $user;
        var $pass;
        var $debug;

        function smtp($host, $port){
            $this->conn = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
            if ($this->conn){
                 $this->Put("HELO $host");
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        function Auth(){
            $this->Put("AUTH LOGIN");
            $this->Put(base64_encode($this->user));
            $this->Put(base64_encode($this->pass));
        }

        function Send($to, $from, $subject, $msg, $nomeexibicao){
            $this->Auth();
            $this->Put("MAIL FROM: " . $from);
            $this->Put("RCPT TO: " . $to);
            $this->Put("DATA");
            $this->Put($this->toHeader($to, $from, $subject, $nomeexibicao));
            $this->Put("\r\n");
            $this->Put($msg);
            $this->Put(".");
            $this->Close();
            if(isset($this->conn)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        function Put($value){
            if ($this->conn) return fwrite($this->conn, $value . "\r\n");
        }

        function toHeader($to, $from, $subject, $nomeexibicao){
            $header = "Message-Id: <". date('YmdHis').".". md5(microtime()).".". strtoupper($from) ."> \r\n";
            $header .= "From: ".$nomeexibicao ."<" . $from . "> \r\n";
            $header .= "To: <".$to."> \r\n";
            $header .= "Subject: ".$subject." \r\n";
            $header .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') ." \r\n";
            $header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal \r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: Text/HTML; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
            $header .= "X-MimeOLE: By Huawei \r\n";
            $header .= "Return-Path: $from\r\n";
            return $header;
        }

        function Close(){
            $this->Put("QUIT");
            if($this->debug == true){
                while (!feof ($this->conn)) {
                    fgets($this->conn) . "<br>\n";
                }
            }
            return fclose($this->conn);
        }

    }


$host = "ssl://p3plcpnl0808.prod.phx3.secureserver.net";
$port = 465;
$smtp = new smtp($host,$port);
$smtp->user = "myemail@server.com";
$smtp->pass = "my_password";

$destinatario = "to_email@server.com";
$remetente = "from_email@server.com";
$assunto = "email title";
$mensagem = "email message";
$nome_exibicao = "My name";
$smtp->Send($destinatario, $remetente, $assunto, $mensagem, $nome_exibicao);
```

when i run it I receive following error:

```
Warning: fwrite(): 12 is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\libs\class.smtp.php on line 45
Warning: fwrite(): 12 is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\libs\class.smtp.php on line 45
Warning: fwrite(): 12 is not a valid stream resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\libs\class.smtp.php on line 45
...
```

the SSL conection is stabilished and resource connection is generated. I don't understand why i'm receiving invalid stream resource if the connection resource exists.

Comment: And line 45 is which line?

Comment: BTW: you _do_ know that there are working, perfectly fine full SMTP client implementations available?

Comment: This code appears to be coded following a stone old tutorial for a long, long outdated php version... Why? The constructor is still named as the class itself and it tries to return a value if it fails which does not make any sense for a constructor.

Comment: Also this implementation completely ignores any response from the server side. So it is completely blind to any issue that arises during the communication. Maybe the server closes the connection after some detail it does not like? Check your http servers error log file, maybe that way you can see something that is wrong.

Comment: The class does not encode any of the injected values like the senders name for example. That means the exchange will fail the moment anything unexpected is used. An extremely fragile implementation that probably also opens further security holes like protocol injection attacks.